# Cloudant Client Database - startKey and endKey - Java

Tags: java, json, eclipse, maven, cloudant

Just for a bit of context, I'm writing a code that connects to a Cloudant database, and retrieves some credentials that are stored in the database, which are in Json format (as you would expect).

I've written code that allows me to connect to the database:

```
public ClientBuilder getCloudantClient(String username, String password) {
        ClientBuilder clientBuilder = ClientBuilder.account(username).
                username(username).password(password);
        return clientBuilder;
    }
```

Then return the database:

```
CloudantClient cloudantClient = cloudantRestClient.getCloudantClient(USERNAME, PASSWORD).build();
Database database = cloudantClient.database(DATABASE, false);
```

Now, I'm trying to retrieve certain credentials from that database, like a certain ID, which is just one line, for example:

```
"id" : "Aberffrawcake"
```

For this [example](http://static.javadoc.io/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/1.1.0/com/cloudant/client/api/View.html) that I've seen, I'd like to specify the startKey, and endKey, which in this case, would be "id", to ideally, return "Aberffrawcake".

Taking into account the above example, I have two main questions:

1. What do the .startKey("id").endKey("id") parameters actually return? According to [this](https://docs.cloudant.com/creating_views.html), they return the starting and ending records with the specified key (but I'm unclear what that means). Is it a Json structure? Is it a regular string? Could someone give me an example of what the the return would be if given a specified starting and ending key?
2. I'm writing a Junit test in eclipse that gives me a null pointer exception when I provide the .startKey("id").endKey("id") parameters. How can I go about in mocking this (with Mochito)? If question 1 becomes clear to me, then I would be able to mock the startKey().endKey() by having them return what I would expect (but since I don't know what they actually return, I'm unable to do this).

I would appreciate any help, and if my question is unclear, please do point it out.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to specify the startKey, and endKey, which in this case,
>   would be "id", to ideally, return "Aberffrawcake".

`startKey` and `endKey` are the range of *values* you're filtering, so in your case it would be "Aberffrawcake" and not "id". For a unique value, `key` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Could you give me an example how .startKey().endKey() work and what they would return if, say, I were to print out the result (if that were possible)? I may not be comprehending the full extend of those methods.

Comment: I don't use Java, but I guess something like `.startKey("{\"id\":\"Aberffrawcake\"}")` or just `.startKey("Aberffrawcake")`

Comment: And what would that return? I've seen here: <http://static.javadoc.io/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.0.0/com/cloudant/client/api/views/SettableViewParameters.Common.html#startKey-K-> that it returns RB, but I'm not sure what that means. I'm asking because I'd like to mock .startKey("Aberffrawcake") in a Junit test.

Comment: See the API doc: https://docs.cloudant.com/creating_views.html#using-views. In fact, the key is the `key`property. It would return a list of docs with 1 element I guess ?

Comment: Oh ok. That helps! But can that return, the list of docs with 1 element for example, be represented in a form of a Java type? As in if I were to write a method that returns the key property, would that method return int, String, something else?

Comment: I can't help you much on the Java side of the thing. The element is of your `Foo` type that you've defined previously (I guess).

Comment: Ok I'll see what that gives me. Thanks for your help!